# Short term residential load forecast

Tags: power

I'm doing a research that involves short term residential load forecast for enery management purposes. I would like to have an idea on what algorithms work best in terms of accuracy and simplicity for this application. I've read about alot of algorithms and I want to learn about other methods, so you guidance would be helpful (its hard to cover all the research in a certain area). My current research showed that Artificial neural networks are the best in terms of accuracy, but my advisor wants me to try something different. I'll be implementing this in Matlab, so if you can provide me of some accurate and suitable algorithms for this application that would be great. Of course I'll keep doing further research from my side as well but I need some help finding my way.
So far I understand that usually forecast uses historical weather and load data and many other factors to prdict the load.  My main concern is that with a single residential unit and I have a  load that is constantly changing (I'm making a sheduling system based on load forecast for home management). With such a small unit and a load that is unprefictible due to the constant rescheduling of the load, how can we do the load forecast?

Note: I'm asking this question after a long time of reaserch and reading and still feeling lost and in need of guidance. This is my first experience in this field.

Thanks

Comment: "*Of course I'll do all the needed research from my side as well ...*" No sign of it in your question, Isra.

Comment: I'm sorry if I can't cite ALL the papers  that I read so far. My question is mainly because I still feel lost so I thought maybe I need to start over from a differenr angle. Appreciate your comment though

Comment: I'm not in that business but I always thought that large grid providers used a combination of historical data, weekly schedules, weather forecasts and, in the days of few channels, kept an eye on the TV guides so they didn't get caught out by several million kettles being switched on in the interval of some big live show. What's changed?

Comment: https://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/188682/files/rlf_humeau.pdf

Comment: A good resource is google scholar if you've ever tried it

Answer (score 2):

You make an important distinction about the size of the population over which the forecast is made. The difference between them is the effect of aggregation of multiple loads. This makes statistical variations smaller for the big population, and reduces the width of the error bars. So the difference is quantitative, not qualitative, and it's just the level of uncertainty.

Ask what the purpose of making the prediction is, as it may affect the choice of algorithm. Is the purpose to make a 'good' prediction of the load in some sense (in exactly what sense?), or is it to minimise the cost of getting it wrong? The cost of a high forecast is the easily quantified cost of 'spare' capacity being kept available, the cost of a low forecast is the irregular cost of importing emergency power, or the very difficult to quantify cost of supply failure (political?). It's like comparing apples with orange painted machine tools. I would guess there's as much work in trying to nail down the cost/benefit of a good/bad prediction as there is in the process of the prediction itself.

Comment: The forecast output is used in a home load scheduling system which will reduce the overall power consumption of the current time interval based on the forecast and some information about the demand or power prices at the current time interval (provided by the utility). The scheduling is done by controlling the individual loads in the home and controlling their working modes. The time intervals will be every hour. My first task is to decide on the right forecasting method for this application. To answer you, the purpose is getting 'good' prediction  to theffpre have 'good' load scheduling.

Comment: @Isra what's theffpre? is that a relative of covfefe? It sounds like the purpose is not then to avoid a blackout if your max estimate is too low, so there's no overwhelming penalty for getting it wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure of what you meant by covfefe. So do you say that in this case a rough estimate of the load should work as well? (I.e accuracy isnt a key?)